# Get Group sum not using group.Sum() in linq

Tags: linq, count, sum, group

The following query works, but I want to get the same result without using grp.Sum(). Can we do it?

```
from item in (await VehicleReplaceCostDataAsync())
                group item by (item.type, item.size, item.ADA, item.eseq) into grp
                orderby (grp.Key.eseq, grp.Key.size, grp.Key.ADA)
                select new VehicleReplacementCost
                {
                    type = grp.Key.type,
                    size = grp.Key.size,
                    ADA = grp.Key.ADA,
                    count = grp.Sum(x => x.count),
                    cost = grp.Sum(x => x.cost),
                    Fcount = grp.Sum(x => x.Fcount),
                    Fcost = grp.Sum(x => x.Fcost),
                    eseq = grp.Key.eseq,
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: It must be asked: why? What's wrong with `Sum`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by using `.Aggregate()`? [[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0)]

```
count = grp.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer from Astrid.  It looks like a good one, but I didn't test it.  My colleague gave this solution instead by using yield:

```
var groups = costs
                .GroupBy(type => (type.SystemId, type.Type, type.Size, type.ADA, type.Eseq))
                .OrderBy(group => (group.Key.SystemId, group.Key.Eseq, group.Key.Size, group.Key.ADA));

 

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                var result = new ProgramGuideVehicleCostRow
                {
                    SystemId = group.Key.SystemId,
                    Type = group.Key.Type,
                    Size = group.Key.Size,
                    ADA = group.Key.ADA,
                };
                foreach (var row in group)
                {
                    result.Cost += row.Cost;
                    result.Fcost += row.Fcost;
                    result.Count += row.Count;
                    result.Fcount += row.Fcount;
                }
                yield return result;
            }
```

Comment: Just to avoid a potential misunderstanding: `.Sum()` has been replaced by logic in a `foreach` loop, not by using `yield`. Also, beware that you are not returning a `List` anymore; see the [yield contextual keyword documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).